# jQuery get each image src attribute and place it as DIV background

Tags: jquery, html, frontend

Please help me with jQuery code.

Need to get each image (img) attribute and place it to the div's background.
I already have this, but its not working in the right way:

```
var $source = $("img").attr("src");
$('div').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'backgroundImage': 'url(' + $source + ')'
    });
});
```

Check link please: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SCqQg/156/)

**PS**.

Adding specific class for each image in not solution because list gonna be very big and dynamic.

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("img").each(function () {
        var $source = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).next("div").css({
            'backgroundImage': 'url(' + $source + ')'
        });

    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yjfysvf7/)

Comment: Yes. The image's src 'this' attribute variable needs to be created in the each I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it. With this, the image will cover the whole div regardless of its size.

```
HTML:
<div class="imagebox"><img src="../img/picture.jpg"></div>
```

.

```
CSS:
.hide { 
   opacity:0; 
}
.imagebox { 
   background-size: cover;  
   background-position: center;
}
```

.

```
CODE:
var imgurl = jQuery("img").attr("src"); // or specific jQuery(".imagebox img").attr("src");
var imgclass = "hide";
jQuery(".imagebox").css("background-image","url("+imgurl+")");
jQuery("img").addClass(imgclass);
```